# How to use MockMVC test the controller which use org.apache.commons.fileupload?

Tags: spring-boot, file-upload, mockmvc

My Controller use " org.apache.commons.fileupload " realized the file UPload.
see it:

```java
 @PostMapping("/upload")
    public String upload2(HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {

        ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload();
        FileItemIterator iter = upload.getItemIterator(request);
        boolean uploaded = false;

        while (iter.hasNext() && !uploaded) {
            FileItemStream item = iter.next();
            if (item.isFormField()) {
                item.openStream().close();
            } else {
                String fieldName = item.getFieldName();
                if (!"file".equals(fieldName)) {
                    item.openStream().close();
                } else {

                    InputStream stream = item.openStream();
                    // dosomething here.
                    uploaded = true;
                }
            }
        }
            if (uploaded) {
                return "ok";
            } else {
                throw new BaseResponseException(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, "400", "no file field or data file is empty.");
            }

        }
```

and my MockMvc code is

```java
    public void upload() throws Exception {
        File file = new File("/Users/jianxiaowen/Documents/a.txt");
        MockMultipartFile multipartFile = new MockMultipartFile("file", new FileInputStream(file));
        HashMap<String, String> contentTypeParams = new HashMap<String, String>();
        contentTypeParams.put("boundary", "----WebKitFormBoundaryaDEFKSFMY18ehkjt");
        MediaType mediaType = new MediaType("multipart", "form-data", contentTypeParams);
        MvcResult mvcResult = mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.post(baseUrl+"/upload")
                .content(multipartFile.getBytes())
                .contentType(mediaType)
                .header(Origin,OriginValue)
                .cookie(cookie))
                .andReturn();
        logResult(mvcResult);
    }
```

my controller is right , it has successed in my web project,
but I want to test it use MvcMock, it has some mistake, see :
 can someOne can help me?

```
"status":"400","msg":"no file field or data file is empty.","data":null
```

I don't know why it says my file is empty.
my English is poor, thank you very much if someone can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try the below?

```
mockMvc.perform(
  MockMvcRequestBuilders.multipart(baseUrl+"/upload")
    .file(multiPartFile)
).andReturn();
```

Update:

You need to update the controller to handle the `MultipartFile`:

```
@PostMapping("/upload")
public String upload2(@RequestParam(name="nameOfRequestParamWhichContainsFileData")
     MultipartFile uploadedFile, HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {
  //the uploaded file gets copied to uploadedFile object. 
}
```

You need not use another library for managing file uploads. You can use the file upload capabilities provided by Spring MVC.

Comment: thank you, i try to modify, but it still show my file is empty.
upload.getItemIterator(request).hasNext() is false

Comment: I have updated my response to include the changes which you need to do in your controller to handle uploads. You need not use third party library to manage file uploads. Its well managed by Spring MVC

Comment: I try to use the file upload capabilities provided by Spring MVC, then the test success ,  In fact I don't known why our company used the "commom.fileupload" before, is there any different performance after I  user the fileupload by SpringMvc? thank you very much！

Comment: Even we were using Commons FileUpload, before we got to know about Spring MultiPartFile. And we haven't found any performance issues after the switch.

Comment: @MohamedSanaulla You might want to use the Streaming capability of Apache FileUpload so it doesn't create a temporary file.

Comment: I will check that for sure. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 5):

The `MockMvc` can be used for integration testing for controllers using [Apache Commons Fileupload](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/) too!

1. Import the [`org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpmime) into your `pom.xml` or `gradle.properties`

   ```html
   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
      <artifactId>httpmime</artifactId>
      <version>4.5.13</version>
   </dependency>
   ```
2. Update the code to use [`MultipartEntityBuilder`](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpmime/4.4/org/apache/http/entity/mime/MultipartEntityBuilder.html) to build the multipart request on the client, and then serialize the entity into bytes, which is then set in the request content

   ```java
   public void upload() throws Exception {
       File file = new File("/Users/jianxiaowen/Documents/a.txt");

       String boundary = "----WebKitFormBoundaryaDEFKSFMY18ehkjt";

       // create 'Content-Type' header for multipart along with boundary
       HashMap<String, String> contentTypeParams = new HashMap<String, String>();
       contentTypeParams.put("boundary", boundary); // set boundary in the header
       MediaType mediaType = new MediaType("multipart", "form-data", contentTypeParams);

       // create a multipart entity builder, and add parts (file/form data)
       ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
       HttpEntity multipartEntity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create()
           .addPart("file", new FileBody(file, ContentType.create("text/plain"), file.getName())) // add file
           // .addTextBody("param1", "value1") // optionally add form data
           .setBoundary(boundary) // set boundary to be used
           .build();
       multipartEntity.writeTo(outputStream); // or getContent() to get content stream
       byte[] content = outputStream.toByteArray(); // serialize the content to bytes

       MvcResult mvcResult = mockMvc.perform(
           MockMvcRequestBuilders.post(baseUrl + "/upload")
               .contentType(mediaType)
               .content(content) // finally set the content
               .header(Origin,OriginValue)
               .cookie(cookie)
           ).andReturn();
       logResult(mvcResult);
   }
   ```

Comment: Finally, a helpful answer. I changed the `FileBody` to a `ByteArrayBody` so I could do everything from code and not rely on anything from the filesystem. But this answer was what I needed. Thank you!